# $scope lost after asynch call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform

I had this working in another project, but when I move the code into a fresh project, the most simple case fails.

My controller looks like this:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers').
  controller('SchoolController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
      $scope.school = "whats wrong";
      var query = new Parse.Query("School");
      query.first().then(function(result){
          $scope.school = "with this";
          alert(result.get("name"));
      });
}]);
```

And the html looks like this:

```
<p>school is {{school}}</p>
```

When rendered, I see "school is what's wrong" on the page as I expect, and I see the alert, including data from the server.  But why don't I see the bound variable on the page change to "with this" ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply your changes to angular:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers').
  controller('SchoolController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
      $scope.school = "whats wrong";
      var query = new Parse.Query("School");
      query.first().then(function(result){
          $scope.school = "with this";
          $scope.$apply();
      });
}]);
```

See `$apply` on [this link](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)

Comment: Right on.  Thank you.  The thing I'm using to wrap parse is smart enough to call apply for me, and my old project was smart enough to state that the parse wrapper is a module dependency, which is why the behavior changed.